# How to prevent a full re-render in REACT if I just want to change a style of a div

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have a situation as following: I'm building a board that's rendered from an array of an array. On key press, the board moves. Since the board can get pretty large, and doesn't change much, I don't want to re-render it every time i'm changing its position. 
Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Here's a partial code:

```
    class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            board: this.createEmptyBoard(),
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress, false);
    }

    handleKeyPress = (e) => {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                this.setState({
                    leftVisible: this.state.left + 10
                });
                break;
            case 39:
                this.setState({
                    leftVisible: this.state.left - 10
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
          <div className="view">
          <Board board={this.state.board} top={this.state.top} left={this.state.left}/>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/* Board Compontent */

class Board extends Component {

    render() {
        const board = this.props.board;
        let boardJSX = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            let tileJSX = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
                tileJSX.push(<div key={"tile-" + i + '-' + j} className={this.classByValue(board[i][j])}></div>);
            }
            boardJSX.push(<div key={"row-" + i} className="board-row">{tileJSX}</div>
            );
        }
        let move = {
            left: this.props.left
        };
        return (
            <div className="board" style={move}>
                {boardJSX}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The virtual DOM is pretty smart. In most cases, you don't need to worry about efficiency. It will only update the nodes that have been modified.

Comment: I would have hoped so, but it takes like 1sec to move the board on each key press. So something here is wrong, and I assume it does re-render it all.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is that rather than having a one giant Board component you can create smaller components and move your changes into child components. React is smart enough to calculate most performance friendly re-renders. Trying to parsing your component logic into smaller ones also will help you to simplify your code and changes in them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PureComponent to prevent unnecessary processing when props/state do not change (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) for a component. In your case you would likely extract each row and/or each tile to their own components, and the have those extend PureComponent.

Note that in general, the best practice is to not prematurely throw PureComponent around everywhere, but in cases like this where you have a fairly large number of components where only a couple are updating at a time, it is usually the way to go.